# Django "Change Page" loading in strange, single-letter scripts, all with 404 error

Tags: django

This issue is really strange. I am in the Django Admin, updating some data.

The "Change page" loads everything ok at first, but then certain Javascript behaviors aren't behaving properly, so I go to check the Javascript console, and I see 22 errors:

First notice the url (in yellow) of my Admin "Change Page":

[image]

and now see all the errors generated from that page (again, notice how the yellow is highlighting the same url as the "Change Page" form above:

[image]

**Now the strangest part of all:**

When I click on the last error, which is:

> localhost/:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Instead of showing me source code from the Django Change Page, it shows me markup from one of my Custom Templates instead! **That should not be happening!**

[image]

Any idea what could be going on here?

Comment: This means that json is trying to load some url that is returning html page instead, you probably have some misconfigured url pattern that catches admin requests.

Comment: Thanks @serg, that could very well be. I will look into it and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

I had been pulling in jQuery into my Admin Page with the following snippet:

```
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # force jquery onto the page
    class Media:
        js = ('templates/js/vendor/jquery-1.12.2.min.js')
```

But because this `js = ()` wasn't technically a tuple (it was missing a comma), it was trying to load scripts onto my admin page like this (notice the last letter in the example url is trying to spell out my string in the code snippet above):

```
example/t
example/e
example/m
example/p
example/l
example/a
example/t
example/e
example/s
example/
...
```

This is why it was pulling in my custom template, because it was hitting the url `example/`, which would have loaded in my custom index page.

**Mystery solved!** I hope this can help someone in the future.